# How should I set up a database with two tables in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-database

As part of my project in my CS class, I have to produce a mobile app. I have got the basics of it down, with a tabbed UI and the forms set up: [form designs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMGIy.png)
The project has to include a database of some kind, and my database needs two tables that link together, as follows: [tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVIkh.png)

Searching around reveals many different ways of setting this up, and many are aimed at a single table, not two interconnected ones. What would be the best method of setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [original documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).
Where they create the Entries table like so

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" 
    ...

db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
```

Just define another SQL_CREATE_OTHER_TABLE string and pass it to `db.execSQL()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreign keys to create a relation between two tables.

```
String CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOCATION + "("
            + KEY_LOCATION_LOCATIONID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_LATITUDE + " REAL, "
            + KEY_LONGITUDE + " REAL, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_LOCATION_SHORTCODE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_LOCATION_SHORTNAME + " TEXT)";

String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCT + "("
            + KEY_PRODUCT_PRODUCTID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + KEY_PRODUCT_CODE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PRODUCT_LOCATIONID + " INTEGER, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_PRODUCT_LOCATIONID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_LOCATION + "(" + KEY_LOCATION_LOCATIONID + ") ON DELETE SET NULL)";
```